# SQL removing duplicates as sets of multiple columns

Tags: sql

Imagine a table like this:

```
RecordID  Key1  Key2
--------------------
1         111   222  
2         222   111  
3         555   444  
4         000   444  
5         444   000
```

As duplicates are considered records having the **same set** on columns `Key1` and `Key2`.

For example, records: (1 and 2) and (4 and 5), are considered duplicates, because they have the same *set* of entries.

So one sample output of the deduplication could be:

```
1         111   222
3         555   444
4         000   444
```

Any ideas how to best achieve this in SQL?

Comment: what rdbms you are using? sqlserver? mysql? oracle? etc..

Answer (score 3):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e8063/1)**

```
SELECT
t1.*
FROM MyTable t1
  LEFT JOIN MyTable t2
    ON t1.Key1 = t2.Key2
      AND t1.Key2 = t2.Key1
      AND t1.RecordID>t2.RecordID
WHERE t2.RecordID is null
```

Result:

```
| RECORDID | KEY1 | KEY2 |
--------------------------
|        1 |  111 |  222 |
|        3 |  555 |  444 |
|        4 |    0 |  444 |
```

Answer (score -1):

This should get the dupe'd records:

```
SELECT alt.RecordID
FROM yourtable AS main
INNER JOIN yourtable AS alt ON (main.Key1 = alt.Key2) AND (main.Key2 = alt.Key1)
```

Comment: It will give you duplicate records not deduped

Answer (score -2):

To get the result you described, you can try:

```
SELECT M1.RecordId
FROM MyTable M1
WHERE Key1 IN (
    SELECT Key2 
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE Key2 = M1.Key1 AND RecordID <> M1.RecordId
    )
    AND
    Key2 IN (
    SELECT Key1
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE Key1 = M1.Key2 AND RecordID <> M1.RecordId
    )
```

To delete the records just use the RecordId...

Something like :

```
DELETE MyTable WHERE RecordId IN ([Previous Query])
```

To get DEDUPLICATE:

```
SELECT  M1.RecordID
FROM    MyTable AS M1 
        LEFT JOIN MyTable AS MK1 ON M1.Key1 = MK1.Key2 AND M1.RecordID <> MK1.RecordID AND MK1.RecordId > M1.RecordId
        LEFT JOIN MyTable AS MK2 ON M1.Key2 = MK2.Key1 AND M1.RecordID <> MK2.RecordID AND MK2.RecordId > M1.RecordId
WHERE MK2.Key1 IS NOT NULL
```

:) SORRY for misunderstood you

Comment: it returns duplicates does not return deduped results

Comment: Sorry , I misunderstood you. -Try: SELECT  M1.RecordID
FROM MyTable AS M1 
  LEFT JOIN MyTable AS MK1 ON M1.Key1 = MK1.Key2 AND M1.RecordID <> MK1.RecordID AND MK1.RecordId > M1.RecordId
        LEFT JOIN MyTable AS MK2 ON M1.Key2 = MK2.Key1 AND M1.RecordID <> MK2.RecordID AND MK2.RecordId > M1.RecordId
WHERE MK2.Key1 IS NOT NULL

Comment: @Luferogo - Your edited solution still doesn't work - it misses out the non-duplicated record:   3         555   444

Comment: @DaveRlz Yes it does. Did you try it? [link to sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a7590/1/0)